# Обобщающее значение у главного слова

Tags: приложение

> Девочки - наши красавицы (-) первые заняли комнату.

Является ли слово **"девочки"** более общим по отношению к **красавицам**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы записала так:

*Девочки, **красавицы наши**, первые заняли комнату.*

Почему именно так? Мне это сообщение **по семантике**  напоминает **вставную или присоединительную** конструкцию  — что-то вроде лирического **отступления** от темы. Но использовать **два тире** в таком предложении было бы странно.

Поэтому делается **инверсия**, чтобы сообщение больше походило на вставку/ присоединение. Тогда мы его обособляем **запятыми**, что допускается правилами.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Если нужно только тире, то ничего не меняем и ставим парный знак (два тире).

Comment: Запятые по условиям задания использовать нельзя!

Comment: Тогда два тире ставьте. Будет  обособленное приложение, это по Розенталю.  Пункт 10(3) для выделения (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего характер пояснения: Какая-то ненатуральная зелень — творение скучных беспрерывных дождей — покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (Г.);  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478426/Обобщающее-значение-у-главного-слова/478436#478436

Answer (score 1):

Наши красавицы - уточнение к девочкам.

Можно подойти по-другому: без второго тире первое зависает.

*Девочки, наши красавицы, первые заняли комнату.*

Comment: Запятые по условиям задания использовать нельзя!

Comment: Тогда два тире.